# Deserialize json to list of KeyValue pairs

Tags: c#, json, c#-6.0

I have the following json:

```
[
   {
      "key":"key1",
      "value":"val1"
   },
   {
      "key":"key2",
      "value":"val2"
   }
]
```

How can I deserialize it into an list/array of `NameValuePair<string, string>`?

Example:

```
var json = "[{\"key\":\"key1\",\"value\":\"val1\"},{\"key\":\"key2\",\"value\":\"val2\"}]";

var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
var result = serializer.Deserialize<List<KeyValuePair<string,string>>>(json);
```

The above code runs but the data inside the list is `null`. I can extract the array into an `List<Object>` though.

Comment: Dont use `JavaScriptSerializer`, use Json.NET

Comment: The linked duplicate is not relevant, that refers to different JSON `{"key1":"value","key2":"value"}`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First off, you should not be using `JavaScriptSerializer`, Microsoft even explicitly says that [in the JavaScriptSerializer docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer(v=vs.110).aspx).

To deserialize an object in Json.NET the syntax is very similar:

```
var json = "[{\"key\":\"key1\",\"value\":\"val1\"},{\"key\":\"key2\",\"value\":\"val2\"}]";
    
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<KeyValuePair<string,string>>>(json);
```

Fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ugQ1vU)

**UPDATE**

If you are using .NET Core 3 / .NET 5 or .NET 6, the [System.Text.Json](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json?view=net-6.0) library is included without an additional dependency.

The syntax for deserializing with that library is:

```
var result =  JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<KeyValuePair<string,string>>>(jsonString);
```